# Three table join sql server to get latest versions and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to count the number of records that have a particular status.

The first table is called Feedback and is structured:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| FeedbackID | Version | Status |
+------------+---------+--------+
|      1     |    1    |  Open  |
+------------+---------+--------+
|      2     |    1    |  Open  |
+------------+---------+--------+
|      2     |   1.1   |  Open  |
+------------+---------+--------+
|      1     |   1.3   |  Open  |
+------------+---------+--------+
|      1     |   1.3   | Closed |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

---

The second ProjectID

```
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| ProjectID | FeedbackID | FeedbackVersion |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     53    |      1     |       1.1       |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     23    |      2     |       1.1       |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     24    |      2     |        1        |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     76    |      2     |       1.1       |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|     76    |      1     |       1.3       |
+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

---

And the third Projects

```
+-----------+--------------+
| ProjectID | Project_Name |
+-----------+--------------+
|     53    |     Test     |
+-----------+--------------+
|     23    | Test Project |
+-----------+--------------+
|     24    |   Feedback   |
+-----------+--------------+
|     76    |     Class    |
+-----------+--------------+
```

---

I'm using these three queries to get the latest versions from the first two tables and I want to compile it all into the third but not sure how to go about joining them all.

```
-- GET Latest Feedback FROM CSLL.Feedback
SELECT fb.ID, fb.Version, fb.Status
FROM CSLL.Feedback fb
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(Version) Version
    FROM CSLL.Feedback
    GROUP BY ID
) MaxVer ON fb.ID = MaxVer.ID AND fb.Version = MaxVer.Version;

-- GET Latest Project FROM CSLL.ProjectID
SELECT Proj.ProjectID, Proj.FeedbackID, Proj.FeedbackVersion
FROM CSLL.ProjectID Proj
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT FeedbackID, MAX(FeedbackVersion) Version
    FROM CSLL.ProjectID
    GROUP BY FeedbackID
) MaxVer ON Proj.FeedbackID = MaxVer.FeedbackID AND Proj.FeedbackVersion = MaxVer.Version;

SELECT 
    Project_ID
    ,Project_Name
    ,(SELECT COUNT(FeedbackID) FROM CSLL.ProjectID WHERE CSLL.ProjectID.ProjectID = CSLL.Projects.Project_ID) AS cnt
FROM CSLL.Projects;
```

I'm trying to get to where the fractional values are got by concatenating the amount of open/closed records together. These could also be done in separate columns

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| ProjectID | Project_Name | Count of Open | Count of Closed |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
|     53    |     Test     |       0       |        0        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
|     23    | Test Project |       1       |        0        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
|     24    |   Feedback   |       0       |        0        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
|     76    |     Class    |       1       |        1        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

---

**Update Code**

I've joined the three tables together using. Now I just need to group by and count the number of status in each project

```
-- GET Latest Project FROM CSLL.ProjectID
SELECT Proj.ProjectID
    ,(SELECT Project_Name FROM CSLL.Projects WHERE CSLL.Projects.Project_ID = proj.ProjectID) AS ProjectName
    ,(SELECT Status FROM CSLL.Feedback WHERE CSLL.Feedback.ID = Proj.FeedbackID AND CSLL.Feedback.Version = Proj.FeedbackVersion) AS Status
    ,(SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM CSLL.Feedback WHERE CSLL.Feedback.ID = Proj.FeedbackID AND CSLL.Feedback.Version = Proj.FeedbackVersion) AS cnt
FROM CSLL.ProjectID Proj
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT FeedbackID, MAX(FeedbackVersion) Version
    FROM CSLL.ProjectID
    GROUP BY FeedbackID
) MaxVer ON Proj.FeedbackID = MaxVer.FeedbackID AND Proj.FeedbackVersion = MaxVer.Version;
```

I'm just struggling to group them together to get the total count

**Update**
Does this make more sense? I've changed the structure of the table a bit as it is more logical

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+
| ProjectID | Project_Name | Status | Count |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+
|     23    | Test Project |  Open  |   1   |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+
|     76    |     Class    |  Open  |   1   |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+
|     76    |     Class    | Closed |   1   |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+

SELECT Proj.ProjectID
    ,(SELECT Project_Name FROM CSLL.Projects WHERE CSLL.Projects.Project_ID = proj.ProjectID) AS ProjectName
    ,(SELECT Status FROM CSLL.Feedback WHERE CSLL.Feedback.ID = Proj.FeedbackID AND CSLL.Feedback.Version = Proj.FeedbackVersion) AS Status
    ,COUNT(Proj.ProjectID) AS cnt
FROM CSLL.ProjectID Proj
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT FeedbackID, MAX(FeedbackVersion) Version
    FROM CSLL.ProjectID
    GROUP BY FeedbackID
) MaxVer ON Proj.FeedbackID = MaxVer.FeedbackID AND Proj.FeedbackVersion = MaxVer.Version
GROUP BY Proj.ProjectID
```

Crude drawing of table structure. I'm trying to summarise the picture

The top two are both projects.

Feedback Items are fed into the projects

I want to get the count of the number of feedback items that are assigned to each project at each status. I'm also only interested in the Feedback that have the highest version.

[image: Crude Table Structure]

Comment: Please show what the final result should look like.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Sorry the third table was how it should look. Have corrected now to show the result I'm trying to achieve and also the third table

Comment: It would help if you explained in plain words how you got these `1/2`, `2/1`, etc. values in the `Count of Status` column. What logic should be behind it?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I've updated my original post. I Have a number of 'projects' that are linked to lots of different items of 'feedback'. Each piece of feedback has an 'open', 'closed', 'action', or 'on hold' status. I'm trying to get the project ID and name along with the count of the number of feedbacks that are attributed to each status. The complication arises due to the fact that each feedback has multiple versions in both of the first two tables. I'm only interested in the latest version

Comment: I don't understand how you got these numbers. For example, `ProjectID=76`, where did `3` come from? where did `4` come from? Rather than showing your attempted code that doesn't do what you need, please explain the required logic using the provided sample data.

Comment: Yes that will make it easier - step through the process of how you came up with these numbers. From your sample data, I don't see how you can get 3 open, 4 closed against project id 76

Comment: I've updated the final table. I would like to concatenate the final two columns but can do this app side.

The Logic is combining the third and first table to the second table. The 3 comes from counting the number of open feedback from the first table that is in that project (e.g. 76) and then returning that count along with the project name (table 3)

Comment: how do you get 3 OPEN for Project 76 from first table ?

Comment: How do versions come into this? We don't seem to have all the sample data for projectid=76. If we consider just projectid=76, is there three open feedback records at the _latest version_ or is there three open feedback records regardless of versions? You first sample table has only two records against feedbackid 2. Can you provide sufficient sample data to reproduce projectid 76?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you're right this was just an extract (there's over 800 rows) I've updated the tables so they should make sense now. I'm only interested in the latest version

Comment: i can see 2 OPEN for Project 76. How do you count it as 1 ?

Comment: can you also explain how do you perfrom the COUNT of OPEN and CLOSE ? Without the logic we are just trying to make guesses based on result

Comment: @Squirrel 1 is closed (FeedbackID 1 Version 1.3) and 1 is open (FeedbackID 2 Version 1.1)

Comment: This is where I'm falling down. I'm trying to effectively expand the third table So that it also includes a summary of statuses and the number of open or closed

Comment: It seems you have already established the correct latest version in table `ProjectID` - is that correct? Would we ever expect to see `project id=76 feedback id=1, versionid=1` in table `ProjectID`, and if so should that record only use the latest version instead of version 1?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Table ProjectID can have multiple versions in it as well but they will match to table 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's still a lot of ambiguity but based on your description so far...

First lets transform the feedback table

This dataset gives you only the latest version as well as two columns corresponding to open and closed:

```
    SELECT 
    FeedbackID, FeedbackVersion,
    CASE WHEN Status='Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As OpenCount
    CASE WHEN Status='Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As ClosedCount
    FROM Feedback F
    WHERE FeedbackVersion = (
             SELECT MAX(FeedbackVersion)
             FROM Feedback FM
             WHERE FM.FeedbackID = F.FeedbackID 
             )
```

Now we just join this back to projects:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, SUM(OpenCount), SUM(ClosedCount)
FROM ProjectID P
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    FeedbackID, FeedbackVersion,
    CASE WHEN Status='Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As OpenCount
    CASE WHEN Status='Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As ClosedCount
    FROM Feedback F
    WHERE FeedbackVersion = (
             SELECT MAX(FeedbackVersion)
             FROM Feedback FM
             WHERE FM.FeedbackID = F.FeedbackID 
             )
) MaxVersion
ON  P.FeedbackID=MaxVersion.FeedbackID
AND P.FeedbackVersion=MaxVersion.FeedbackVersion
GROUP BY P.ProjectID
```

It's not clear what you want to do with `ProjectID` records with old versions. i.e. if project id 7 *only* exists in `ProjectID` against an old version, it will not appear in this query.

Comment: When I try to run the first query I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.`

Comment: I forgot a comma. I'll fix it